# Animate an object array along a path with curve modifier

Tags: animation

I'm working on an industrial conveyor belt and trying to animate it but can't figure out how to make it run.

It's a single object with an array to multiply it, deformed with a curve modifier.

I tried pretty much avery axis to move it, but it either stays still or move on the side.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, in my curve settings i ticked "Bounds Clamp" and that prevented me from moving my object in the correct axis. Thanks lemon !

Answer (score 3):

You can parent the belt to another object (an empty for instance).

Then simply move the empty in the appropriate axis (along x in the blend file attached below).

[image]

You can also move the object itself along the same axis.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem persists, the axis into which I want to move the object is locked. I tried applying the rotation and change de deformation axis but it doesn't seem to work better..

Comment: @ThibautTuabit, you should upload your blend file (editing your question) so that we can have a look at your issue.

Comment: Sure, thank you